# Entity Framework - seemingly simple question

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, poco

Long time listener, first time caller...

So I'm converting an existing app over to ef. I am enjoying the experience so far. I have a POCO class that has some simple user properties.

ex.

```
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
other properties...
public string FullName
{
    get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; }
}
```

How do I accomplish this with EF? Can is be done in the EDM, or do I have to create a partial class? I prefer the EDM...

Comment: if this is Poco , then you just need to add [NotMapped] attribute to FullName property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need partial class because this is property computed in your code not in database. Problem here is that read/write entity must have only properties mapped to a table but your table probably doesn't have `FullName` column = you can't map it and you can't use it in queries. Computed properties in EDM are possible but only if you have read only entity defined by [Query view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716798.aspx) (view defined in ESQL) or [Defining query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738450.aspx) (custom SQL select). If you want to use `FullName` in query you must define it as [model defined function](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/ef4-model-defined-functions-level-1-amp-2/). [Query view, Defining Query](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/edm-queryviews-vs-defining-queries-and-read-only-views/) and model defined functions are advanced EF features which are not available in designer. You must open EDMX as XML and edit it manually.

Comment: Does this then break the design view like in EF1? * I read that somewhere last week

Comment: I don't think so. I used all these features with EFv4 and they worked. The problem is with `DefiningQuery` - once you use it you can't use update from database. Update from database override it.

Comment: What about a stored procedure to pull the table plus the 'extra' column? that way it would come across and I know enough not to try and update it. Could I then make that property read only in EDM? I'm trying to stick with KISS.                                                   *EDIT* I found this blog post, which quasi explains my issue/resolution: http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/a-big-step-for-stored-procedures-in-ef4/

Comment: I've used a partial class. It's only for eval expressions. Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a POCO architecture you may want to consider using EF4 CodeFirst.  It allows you to use your existing POCO classes "as-is", no rework of things like computed properties required, and you just wire them up to a DBContext that you configure in code.

The approach is pretty attractive to most POCO folks and it's made me give EF a second look.  Scot Gu introduces it in this post http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx and he's done a series of articles since that give lot's of detail on how to configure persistence with CodeFirst.